# in a while loop, where should you place a variable for counting?

Tags: python, while-loop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l1oi.png)

Please excuse me that I'm posting my code as an image.
This is a simple guessing game expression.

When you look at the last line of the code, 
there is 'tries += 1' code to count how many times it's looped.

So my question is,
the result is changing when I put 'tries += 1' right under
the code line 'guess = input("What is your lucky number?")'.

So what is the difference between
putting it at the last line of the code block and right under the start of while loop code.

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Juyoung. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Show code and error message as properly formatted text in the question, not as image (instead of apologising for it).

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference in this particular case, since there is no `break` or `return` or `continue` in your loop. But since you posted the code as an image and my IDE can't run images, I can't test it for myself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it have been far easier to just copy in the text than to print-screen and crop the image? The number of tries is initialized to 1 which is misleading as at that point in the program there hasn't been any tries. Logically it makes more sense to initialize tries to 0 and place the increment immediately after the user input. But because the program hasn't been structured in this way, tries must be incremented after comparing the guess to the target; otherwise, in the case when the user's guess is correct, the output would show a number of tries one greater than the actual number of tries.

Answer (score 0):

What you're misunderstanding is the order in which your code executes. There are three important events inside your loop:

1. You ask the user for their guess
2. You process their guess, and if they get it right you display the *current value* of the variable `tries`
3. You increment the variable `tries`, in the statement `tries += 1`

These execute in exactly that order. So, when the user guesses correctly, they're told the value of `tries` *before* it is incremented again. If you put the line `tries += 1` right after the input statement, then that value is now being increased before it is printed. Thus, the displayed value is different.